# A question about permutation on higher order tensors

Tags: permutations, tensors

I'm trying to understand the following definition.

Let $[n]:= \{1, \dots , n\}$ and consider the set of permutations $S_n$. For $G \in \mathbb{R}^{n^k}$ (a high-order tensor representing some hyper-graph) and $\sigma \in S_n$, we define

$$(\sigma \star G)_{\sigma(i_1), \dots \sigma(i_k)} = G_{i_1, \dots, i_k}$$

Does this just mean that applying again the same permutation I get to the original ordering of the tensor dimensions?

I would have better understood something like

$$\sigma \star G_{i_1, \dots i_k} = G_{\sigma(i_1), \dots , \sigma(i_k)}$$

Comment: I think it amounts to your formula with $\sigma^{-1}$ on the RHS instead of $\sigma$.

Comment: I'm reading this definition on the https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.04943.pdf I got your point I also think it should be ok with $\simga^{-1}$ even though I can't see this on paper